# Reversing words in shell

Tags: linux, string, shell, awk

Task is to reverse all letters (a-zA-Z) in words that have 5 or less characters.

EDIT: Let's assume word is a not interrupted sequence of letters from english alphabet.

( letter: [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) range A-Z && a-z)

Example:

Input: `"One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them, One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them."`

Output: `"enO gnir ot elur meht lla, eno gnir ot dnif meht, enO gnir ot gnirb meht lla dna ni eht darkness dnib meht."`

I have been able to write this script, but it sruggles with words with special chracters such as {,.} that are not supposed to be reversed.

```
#!/bin/bash

    word_length=0
    touch tmp 

    for word in $(cat ./TEXT)
    do
            word_length=$(echo -n $word | wc -c )
            if [ $word_length -le 5 ] 
            then
                    echo -n $word | rev >> tmp 
                    echo -n " " >> tmp 
            else
                    echo -n $word >> tmp 
                    echo -n " " >> tmp 
            fi
    done

    cat tmp > TEXT
    echo " " >> TEXT
    rm -rf tmp
```

Output of this script: 
`"enO gnir ot elur meht ,lla eno gnir ot dnif ,meht enO gnir ot gnirb meht lla dna ni eht darkness dnib .meht"`

You can see that {,.} are in the wrong place.

Comment: Is `O'Donnell` a word? How about `1234`? How about `there's`? Clarify what you mean by a "word" and include examples of those in your sample input/output, not just the absolutely trivial cases of all alphabetic characters.

Comment: Given your updated requirement that `word is a not interrupted sequence of letters from english alphabet` - so is `pre-existing` 2 words that should become `erp-existing` or something else?

Comment: `"O'Donnell"` => 2 words `"O"` and `"Donnell"`, `"1234"` is not a word, `"there's"` => 2 words, `"pre-existing"` also 2 words `"pre"` and `"existing"`

Comment: Ok so `pre-existing` should become `erp-existing` as it's 2 separate words. You should include that example (and probably others) in your sample input/output as most or all of the posted scripts that do what you show in your example will fail for other possible use cases. I see you accepted an answer that involves multiple shell loops. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for some of the reasons that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` code for this:

```
awk 'function revw(wrd) {
   if (wrd ~ /[^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+$/ || length(wrd) > 5)
      return wrd
   nw = wrd
   sub(/^[a-zA-Z]+/, "", nw)
   sub(/[^a-zA-Z]+$/, "", wrd)
   rw = ""
   for (j=length(wrd); j>0; j--)
      rw = rw substr(wrd, j, 1)
   return rw nw
}
{
   line = ""
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      line = line revw($i) (i==NF ? "" : OFS)
   print line
}' file

enO gnir ot elur meht lla, eno gnir ot dnif meht, enO gnir ot gnirb meht lla dna ni eht darkness dnib meht.
```

Comment: Wouldn't that convert a word like `pre-existing` to `preexisting-` or `someone's` to `someones'`?

Comment: Good point Ed. I had assumed that non-alpha characters are only at the end of a word. I made a change which will leave `pre-existing` and `someone's` as is.

Comment: Given what the OP has told us so far I just don't know if `pre-existing` should be output as-is or become `erp-existing`. I guess she'll let us know if there's any issues...

Comment: Based on my understanding it looks like OP is dealing with dictionary words containing English alphabets only. There can be usual punctuation characters trailing those words.

Answer (score 1):

With `for word in $(cat ./TEXT)`,
it may look like you iterate over *words* of the input,
but Bash has a different definition of words than what you might expect.
In the above statement,
Bash performs *word splitting*,
but that just means splitting by the value of `IFS`.
By default this value is sequence of whitespace characters.
Which means that punctuation will be part of the words.

> Task is to reverse all letters (a-zA-Z) in words that have 5 or less characters.

For a robust solution,
consider this algorithm:

- Initialize `word` to be the empty string
- For each character `c` in the input
- If `c` is a letter, append it to `word`
- Otherwise:

  - If `word` is longer then 4 characters, print it
  - Or else if `word` is not empty, reverse it
  - Reset `word` to empty
  - Print `c`
- After the loop, print `word`, to make sure the last word gets printed

Using pure Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

s=$(cat ./TEXT)

print_reverse() {
    local w=$1
    local i
    reversed=
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#w}; i++)); do
        reversed=${w:i:1}$reversed
    done
    printf "$reversed"
}

print_word() {
    local w=$1
    if [ ${#w} -gt 4 ]; then
        printf "$w"
    elif [ "$w" ]; then
        print_reverse "$w"
    fi
}

word=
for ((i = 0; i < ${#s}; i++)); do
    c=${s:i:1}
    case "$c" in
        [a-zA-Z]) word=$word$c ;;
        *)
            print_word "$word"
            word=
            printf "$c"
            ;;
    esac
done

print_word "$word"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to separate the `.` and `,` from your words.
You can:

1. change the first `cat ./TEXT` with `sed -r 's/([,.])/ \1/g' ./TEXT` which add a space before those character
2. then when the output is done reverse the sed `sed -r 's/ ([,.])/\1/g' ./TEXT` which remove the white space added before (In your example your TEXT file has one word by line but I took the hypothesis you'll will correct this)

But, this will be limited to the character put in the sed like `,.':;` if new characters occurs you'll have to change the script

Beside, why a limit of 5 characters to reverse a word ? In your example darkness is not reverse because of this.

Answer (score 0):

another `gawk`

```
gawk -v RS='[^a-zA-Z]' 'function rev(x,rx) {n=split(x,a,"");
                                           while(n) rx=rx a[n--];
                                           return rx}

             {printf "%s", (length()>5?$0:rev($0)) RT}' file


enO gnir ot elur meht lla, eno gnir ot dnif meht, enO gnir ot gnirb meht lla dna ni eht darkness dnib meht.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `bash` approach, note that this code will convert the apostrophe in word like `don't` to `tnod'` :-

```
while read line
do
        printf "$line\n"
        for word in $line
        do
                for (( i = ${#word}; i >= 0; i-- ))
                do
                        if [[ "${word:$i:1}" =~ '[[:alpha:]]' ]]
                        then
                                printf "${word:$i:1}"
                        else
                                symb="${word:$i:1}"
                        fi
                done
                printf "${symb} "
        done
        printf "\n"
done < TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
$ cat ip.txt
"One ring to rule them all,
one ring to find them,
One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them."
O'Donnell 1234 there's pre-existing

$ perl -F'/([^a-z])/i' -ane '
          print map {$_ = length()<6 && /[a-z]/i ? reverse : $_} @F' ip.txt
"enO gnir ot elur meht lla,
eno gnir ot dnif meht,
enO gnir ot gnirb meht lla dna ni eht darkness dnib meht."
O'Donnell 1234 ereht's erp-existing
```

- `-F'/([^a-z])/i'` use non alphabets as field separator, use of `()` means the field separators would be also be saved in `@F` array along with word fields

  - see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for explanation of command line options
- `map` is used to transform each element of array
- `length()<6 && /[a-z]/i` condition to select words less than length 6 and to ignore field separators
- `reverse` will reverse the string in scalar context
- finally the changed array is printed